# Product of unique prime factors of a number

Tags: number-theory, terminology, prime-factorization

Given $n=p^x q^y r^z$ (with p, q, and r prime), is there a name for the number $m = p q r $ or the function f(n) = m?

Eg.,
For $n = 52 = 2*2*13$, $m = 2*13 = 26$
For $n = 3300 = 2*2*3*5*5*11$, $m = 2*3*5*11 = 330$

Comment: It's called [the radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer)

Comment: Also the [square-free kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer#Properties), the [largest square-free factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer#Square-free_factors_of_integers) or the largest square-free divisor.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies and the links! Is it useful to have the question up for later users, and if so could you add these as answers so I can accept one? (or if it's too basic a question to keep, mods please feel free to delete it).

Comment: Actually, for definitions [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) is a reference for later users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the [radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) of the integer. $$\text {rad} (n) = \prod_{p\,|\,n} p$$ 
where the product is taken over primes dividing $n$.

Quite a useful concept, which has gained some attention lately owing to its appearance in the [abc conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture).